# PUT verb on IIS6 creating a file

Tags: rest, wcf-rest, http-put

I have a WCF REST webservice with a PUT method which I have deployed on an IIS6 server. When I  request to PUT a resource, the web service never gets hit. Instead a file gets created on the root folder whose content is the JSON post body.

Why is the request not hitting the service? This seems to be a problem with the PUT verb. GET and POST work as expected.